Не с относительным прилагательным пишется

Я отдыхаю на не морском побережье.
Я отдыхаю не на морском побережье.
Я отдыхаю на неморском побережье.

Одинаковы ли смыслы в данном случае?
Правило правописания "не" с относительными прилагательными сформулировано весьма странно: "обычно раздельно".

https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/270140#question

@Арчи Их ответ слишком размыт: "обычно раздельно", "обычно распространяется", "может не распространяться".  Нет конкретики.

Правильно:
(1) Я отдыхаю не на морском побережье.
(2) Я отдыхаю на неморском побережье.
Пояснение

При раздельном написании НЕ по контексту подразумевается отрицание: не на морском побережье, а где-либо еще.

Сочетание на не морском побережье некорректно, так как в позиции определения по правилам Розенталя используется только утвердительная конструкция: на неморском побережье.

Но в словаре нет слова  неморской, образованного от относительного прилагательного? Но есть правило Розенталя и ПАС, где говорится о возможности слитного написания НЕ.


В этом случае сопоставляются значения морской и неморской (приставка НЕ обозначает непринадлежность к какому-либо разряду лиц или  явлений).  К примеру, у Розенталя в § 56, пункт 3 есть аналогичное сопоставление литераторы и нелитераторы.
При образовании пары морской/неморской относительное прилагательное приобретает конкретное качественное значение.
Морское побережье – это полоса суши, примыкающая к морю, рельеф которой носит следы взаимодействия с морем, а морской воздух и вода имеет свои особенности. Соответственно, возможен вариант "неморское побережье", где нет таких признаков.

Примеры:

Самара вошла в список десяти лучших неморских курортов России для осеннего отдыха.
Иногда пишут кавычки, но это лишнее. В список десяти лучших «неморских» курортов России для осеннего отдыха вошли Сортавала, Абрау-Дюрсо и Пятигорск.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
§ 57. Частица не с прилагательными
 4. Как правило, частица не пишется раздельно с 
 **относительными прилагательными,** выражая отрицание 
 обозначаемого ими признака: часы не золотые; мёд не 
липовый; небо здесь не южное.

 При этом учитывается синтаксическая функция 
 прилагательного. Правило обычно распространяется на 
 прилагательные, выступающие в роли сказуемого, так как 
 предполагаемое противопоставление придает высказыванию 
 характер общеотрицательного суждения, выражаемого частицей 
 не, но может не распространяться на прилагательные, 
 выполняющие функцию определения. Ср.: эти люди не здешние — 
 блистать нездешней красотой; 

§ 148. С существительными, прилагательными, наречиями на -о отрицание не пишется слитно в следующих случаях.
2. Если существительные и прилагательные в сочетании с не 
обозначают непринадлежность к какому-либо разряду лиц или 
явлений, напр.: Нерусский взглянет без любви / На эту 
бледную, в крови, / Кнутом иссеченную музу (Некр.); 
неакадемические институты, непищевые добавки, невоенные 
отрасли.


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Одинаковы ли смыслы в данном случае?
Смыслы крайне близкие, поэтому я считаю, что в общем случае фразы взаимозаменяемы. Не помешает отметить небольшие нюансы:
"Я отдыхаю на не морском побережье".

Акцент делается на противопоставление морскому побережью.
Диалог развивался примерно так:
— Как я не люблю море! Вот реки, озёра, м-м....
— Полностью согласен! Я отдыхаю на не морском побережье всегда.
— Мы так похожи!

"Я отдыхаю не на морском побережье". 
Эта фраза акцентирует внимание на том, что побережье именно не морское.
Возможно, диалог был такой:
— Я на побережье.
— На море поехал? Когда успел?
— Я отдыхаю не на морском побережье. Я у озера.

"Я отдыхаю на неморском побережье".
Это более лаконичный и однозначный вариант с указанием на конкретное качество побережья.
Диалог был примерно такой:
— Ты на каком побережье отдыхаешь?
— Я отдыхаю на неморском побережье. Я у озера.
— О-о, можно я подъеду?


А правописание? Чем оправдано следование слитному написанию?
